# Change the background color of body when value of input with type of range is change

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an input of a range type. When the value of input range change I want to change the background color of the body.

Here is the HTML

```
<div class="range">
    <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="0" class="slider" id="myRange">
</div>
```

Here is the Javascript Code

```
let slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
slider.onchange = () => {
    document.body.style.background = `linear-gradient(90deg,  #2b2e43 0%,#2b2e43 50%,#ffffff 50.1%,#ffffff 100%);`
}
```

Comment: Should the value given to the `<input>` correspond to the value of the gradient?

Comment: No. just simply change the background color. no matter whats the value of the input is

Comment: Please check your source, it might be just a syntax error.
Also the error will be viewed in `DevTools` of browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified it a little but basically the main issue is you have added a semi colon to the value in the JS code which is not required.

```js
  function updateSlider() {
      document.body.style.background = `linear-gradient(90deg,  #2b2e43 0%,#2b2e43 50%,#ffffff 50.1%,#ffffff 100%)`;
 
  }
```

```html
<div class="range">
    <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="0" class="slider" id="myRange" onchange="updateSlider()">
</div>
```